# Как использовать netflix eureka и feign без spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, spring-boot, облако

Добрый день. Я пытаюсь перейти на микросервисную архитектуру. У меня есть сервер `eureka` и сервисы которые взаимодействуют между собой с помощью `Feign`. Но к сожалению так же есть очень большое web приложения с `jsf, spring, hibernate` и т.д. которое я не могу переписать на `spring-boot`, но которое обязательно должно так же взаимодествовать с остальными сервисами. В подключении в него любых библиотек типа `spring-cloud` или чего-то наподобия я не ограничен. Как я могу использовать в нем `eureka и feign`? Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь в таком случае вам понадобиться не только feign - feign это всего лишь враппер над http клиентом. Для доступа к сервисам по имени, необходимо подключиь и настроить Ribbon.

За помощью можно обратиться в официальную документацию Ribbon: [ribbon](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon)
Там же есть и описание ribbon-eureka.

Spring-Boot уже сам конфигурирует Feign клиентов для работы с Ribbon. Не уверен, что это в конечном итоге вообще пригодится, но если будет нужно, знания можно черпать из процесса конфигурирования Feign в проекте spring boot netflix. Начать стоит с класса [FeignClientsRegistrar](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/feign/FeignClientsRegistrar.java)

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать подключить спрингбутовский стартер, например **spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server**. Залезть в jar этого стартера и посмотреть файл **META-INF/spring.factories**:

org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
  **org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerAutoConfiguration**

А теперь заимпортить эту конфигурацию самому:
**@Import(EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.class)**